# How to check against the wrong nameerror

Tags: ruby, exception

So I'm trying to get a class out of the value of the class:

```
bucket.product_name.constantize #=> want to check if that fails
```

However sometimes the application bugs me with:

```
NameError: wrong constant name a
```

So I assume there is some weird `product_name`s that has either `nil` value or corrupted value: such as `a`.

How would you check if that is NameError issue?

Say,

`"a".constantize if "a".constantize != NameError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defined?("a") == "constant"

# => true if "a" is a valid constant name
# => false otherwise
```

Using this:

```
name = bucket.product_name
name.constantize if defined?(name) == "constant"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too obvious, but just in case:

```
begin
  "a".constantize
rescue NameError
  # handle error here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Definitely a good answer. However I wanted to know what condition can identify the issue